# sched_setscheduler is for all threads or main thread?

Tags: c, linux, scheduled-tasks, thread-priority

I have the following source which like to have SCHED_RR priority 90 :

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const char *sched_policy[] = {
    "SCHED_OTHER",
    "SCHED_FIFO",
    "SCHED_RR",
    "SCHED_BATCH"
    };
    struct sched_param sp = {
        .sched_priority = 90
    };
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    printf("pid=(%d)\n",pid);
    sched_setscheduler(pid, SCHED_RR, &sp);
    printf("Scheduler Policy is %s.\n", sched_policy[sched_getscheduler(pid)]);

    pthread_t tid ;
    pthread_create(&tid , NULL, Thread1 , (void*)(long)3);
    pthread_create(&tid , NULL, Thread2 , (void*)(long)3);
    pthread_create(&tid , NULL, Thread3 , (void*)(long)3);
    while(1)
        sleep(100);
}
```

while shell "top" , I can see that process has PR with -91 , look like it works,
As I know , in Linux , thread1 and thread2 and thread3 are different tasks
from the main thread , they just share the same virtual memory , I like to know
in this test , should I need to add

```
pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_RR, &sp);
```

for all thread1,thread2 and thread3 so that all these 3 can be scheduled
with SCHED_RR ?!   or  I don't need to do that ?!  and how can I observe 
that thread1,thread2 and thread3 thread are SCHED_RR or SCHED_OTHER ?!

Edit :

```
sudo chrt -v -r 90 ./xxx.exe
```

will see :

```
pid 7187's new scheduling policy: SCHED_RR
pid 7187's new scheduling priority: 90
```

how can I be sure this is only for main thread ?! or all threads in pid 7187
are SCHED_RR policy ?!  and again , how to observe it ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shall check (and set, if required) the scheduler inheritance attributes before creating any new thread.

`int pthread_attr_getinheritsched(const pthread_attr_t *attr, int *inheritsched);`

`int pthread_attr_setinheritsched(pthread_attr_t *attr, int inheritsched);`

The `pthread_attr_getinheritsched()` will store in the variable pointed by `inheritsched` one of two possible values:

- > **PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED** - Threads  that  are  created  using   attr
  >   inherit   scheduling attributes  from  the creating thread; the
  >   scheduling attributes in attr are ignored.
- > **PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED** - Threads that  are  created  using  attr  take
  >   their  scheduling attributes from the values specified by the
  >   attributes object.

If you want that every newly created thread inherits the scheduler attributes of the calling task, you should set PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED (if not already set).

**Also note:**

> The  default setting of the inherit-scheduler attribute in a newly
>   initialized thread attributes object is **PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED**

**References**

```
$ man pthread_setschedparam
$ man pthread_attr_setinheritsched
```

- (Blockquoted material was copied from parts of release 3.74 of the Linux man-pages project.)